# Windows 10 — how to remove a user from logon screen?

Tags: windows-10, login, windows-10-v1803

I'm using Windows 10 (1803) and since I'm the only user of my PC I've enabled autologon using **netplwiz**:

[image]

It worked fine for a long time but after some newer updates (still no 1809!) there is a second user profile with my name and a message that the password I've entered is wrong on logon screen:

[image]

…so the autologon doesn't succeed and I have to choose my account manually and enter my PIN.

Is there a way to remove this second user from the logon screen?

[image]

Comment: Does  disabling and re-enabling autologon using netplwiz change anything? (I can't read the images fyi, maybe it won't matter)

Comment: @Xen2050 for some reason it seems actually to do the job! Thank you!

Comment: That's good news, I might as well make it an official answer (Welcome!)

Comment: I had this problem on a VM of mine.  I simply set the default user account again and doing so solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling and re-enabling autologon using netplwiz.

Something must have changed during an update, but netplwiz might be able to re-set things back to working.